# Global query scope , Multi-tenant architecture

Tags: laravel, architecture, multi-tenant, laravel-3, global-scope

I'm trying modify the existing code to do Global query scoping in Laravel 3!! for multi-tenant architecture.

Need some idea in terms of, how multi-tenant architecture is achievable in laravel 3

Thanks in advance :)